# how we can integrate more option in welcome wizard in MDT

Tags: deployment, microsoft, wds, mdt, adk

Want to integrate more option in welcome wizard like

1. Windows 11
2. Windows 10
3. Blancco
4. Dart

Just like screenshot attached for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Have you consider using Ventoy instead of MDT?